# How to simply do parametric dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I am experimenting with using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` for a UI application, simply because an interesting UI framework employs it. However, for this use-case, it seems limited, based on my current understanding. A common use-case for this domain would be to specialize construction at use-site.

Let's say we register a service on program startup:

```
services.AddScoped<IWorkspace, Workspace>();
```

When the user wants to open a new workspace, this workspace will require some parameters unique to that instantiation, as there can be multiple workspaces, and the exact path of the workspace is not statically fixed.

One way, would be for the constructed type to require post-construction initialization:

```
var workspace = workspaceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorkspace>();
workspace.Initialize(pathToWorkspace);
```

Some argue for injecting a factory, where one could do:

```
var workspaceProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorkspaceProvider>();
var workspace = workspaceProvider.New(pathToWorkspace);
```

That would probably suffice and be okay for just a simple case like this. However, if one were to apply this pattern to many more types, then it seems quite boilerplate-heavy to me.

Keyed services in .NET 8 do not seem useful in this case, as the key has to be known ahead of time, as it is registered when the `IServiceProvider` is configured.

Is there a simpler way to do it?

I was thinking more along the lines of:

```
var workspacePath = new WorkspacePath(someWorkspacePathString);
var workspace = serviceProvider.WithTransient<WorkspacePath>(workspacePath).GetRequiredService<IWorkspace>();
```

Kind of like "partial application for dependency injection". We partially register dependencies required to create an instance and then supply the remaining dependencies at the use-site (`WithTransient`). This would then also control when to create a new instance, and when to reuse an existing instance, since `WithTransient` would specify the parameters giving uniqueness to each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options):

1. Create class with properties for every parameter you need:

```cs
public class WorkspaceOptions {
  public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

2a. Put appropriate data in appsettings.json and bind it to class:

```json
{
  "MyWorkspaceOptions" : {
    "Path": "/put/your/path/here"
  }
}
```

```cs
services.Configure<WorkspaceOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyWorkspaceOptions"));
services.AddScoped<IWorkspace, Workspace>();
```

2b. Or assign values directly in code:

```cs
services.Configure<WorkspaceOptions>(opt => {
  opt.Path = "/some/path";
});
services.AddScoped<IWorkspace, Workspace>();
```

3. Request your options in Workspace constructor and use where needed:

```
public class Workspace: IWorkspace {
  private readonly WorkspaceOptions options;

  public Workspace(IOptions<WorkspaceOptions> myOptions) {
    options = myOptions.Value;
  }

  public void Foo() {
    var myFile = options.Path + "/filename.txt";
    ...
  }
}
```

You may even replace `IOptions<>` with [`IOptionsSnapshot<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#options-interfaces) and make your app auto-update values without restart when you edit appsettings.json.

Comment: All workspaces can’t point to the same directory or they’d be equivalent. Essentially the user points out the location for each workspace on demand. 

Comment: So, you can't pre-register Workspace at startup with correct directory (because it's not known yet), so you need something like "Workspace.Init" to call after you get in from DI.
And if your users can work with different Workspaces concurrently - you must register them with correct scope to make sure every user will get it own instance.